# Angular2 Multidimensional array ng-for not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I am using Angular2, all working good, but am unable to printout multidimensional arrays, here is the code:

```
class AppComponent {
    items:Array<Object>;
    constructor(http: Http) {
    http.get('data.json')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .subscribe(data => this.items = data);
  }
}
```

#### First example with simple non-multidimensional array works as expected

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "v2": "L'Oréal Paris",
    "v4": "Serum Absolute Advanced Age-Reversing Makeup"
}]

<div *ng-for="#item of items">
    {{item.v2}} {{item.v4}}
</div>
```

#### Problem that emits error and does not work:

```
[{
    "4940": {
        "id": "4940",
        "v2": "Pantene Pro-V",
        "v4": "Cleansing Conditioner"
},
    "4941": {
        "id": "4941",
        "v2": "Pantene Pro-V",
        "v4": "Conditioner"
},
    "4942": {
        "id": "4942",
        "v2": "Pantene Pro-V",
        "v4": "2in1 Shampoo and Conditioner"
}]


<div *ng-for="#item of items">
  <div *ng-for="#itemone of item">
    {{itemone.v2}} {{itemone.v4}}
  </div>
</div>
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

**I've found a solution, you need to convert object to array before loop:**

```
<div *ng-for="#item of items">
  <div *ng-for="#itemone of item | objToArr">
    {{itemone.v2}} {{itemone.v4}}
  </div>
</div>
```

**And here is the Pipe:**

```
import { Pipe } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Pipe({
  name: 'objToArr',
  pure: false
})
export class ObjToArr {
  transform(object:any) {
    var newArray = []
    for (var key in object) {
        newArray.push(object[key]);
    }
    return newArray;
  }
}
```

Comment: The data does not seem to be a multidimensional array as you state, its just an array of objects with objects. Thats why its not working.

Comment: get rid of the id object keys in your data. They are rarely needed and you already have the `id` in each object. Your main array consist of one big object that isn't sortable or filterable

Comment: Oh my god, my eyes.. Why the caps lock, [why are you yelling](http://theoatmeal.com/comics/minor_differences)?!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to flat the object, that could work here.

But, how can I use many multidimensional array/object/whatever..  to list data the way I described? I used to play with arrays no problem in PHP, and I have a lot of problems handling data in JS/A2, I cant figure out how to make simple multidimensional object/array/...  and just use multiple FOREACH to loop thru that multidimensional array/object..

I do not know how is it possible that nowhere on the net is available any info on this problem. Does anyone use multidimensional data in JS at all?

Answer (score 0):

As per the update in question, you need to convert object to array before looping over it:

```
<div *ng-for="#item of items">
  <div *ng-for="#itemone of item | objToArr">
    {{itemone.v2}} {{itemone.v4}}
  </div>
</div>
```

The pipe used is below:

```
import { Pipe } from 'angular2/angular2';

@Pipe({
  name: 'objToArr',
  pure: false
})
export class ObjToArr {
  transform(object:any) {
    var newArray = []
    for (var key in object) {
        newArray.push(object[key]);
    }
    return newArray;
  }
}
```